# LuaJIT undefined references

Tags: c, lua, linker, luajit

I'm trying to compile and link the following C program against `liblluajit-5.1` (I have LuaJIT version `2.0.5` installed on Linux):

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int status;

  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
  luaL_openlibs(L);

  lua_getglobal(L, "require");
  lua_pushliteral(L, "mod");

  lua_pcall(L, 1, 0, 0);

  // ...

  return 0;
}
```

This fails because of undefined references to `lua_getglobal` and `lua_pcallk`. Why? Does LuaJIT only implement a subset of the C API and I have to additionally link against `liblua`?

I'm compiling and linking with:

```
gcc -Wl,-E -o prog prog.c -lluajit-5.1 -lm -ldl
```

Comment: Maybe it's not able to find that library in the path. Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/lluajit-5.1` before running `gcc`.

Comment: @kiner_shah: GCC definitely finds luajit, it's right under `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Is `/usr/lib` in your system path? How did you check that GCC finds the library?

Comment: And also, is your include path also there in the system path? If yes, then which header files have those two functions? Also, you can check if a function is present in a library by using `strings /usr/lib/<library_name> | grep "lua_getglobal"` command or `nm` command.

Comment: Actually the includes were the issue, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was simply this: I had to include

```
#include "luajit-2.0/lua.h"
#include "luajit-2.0/lauxlib.h"
#include "luajit-2.0/lualib.h"
```

instead of the standard Lua headers.

Comment: Might have been that the system Lua headers were for Lua 5.3 or a more recent version, while LuaJIT exposes a Lua 5.1 API.